# Retrieve data from dynamic php page to javascript using jquery

Tags: php, javascript, json

This is arrivalPlay.php. This page is loaded if user click data from arrivalRead.php and make the url become arrivalPlay.php?id=1 (2,3,4,5 and so on).

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","admin","admin","flight_status");
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $getrow = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM arrival WHERE id='$id'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($getrow);
    mysqli_close($con); 
    $order = array(1,2,3,4);
    foreach ($order as $o) {
        $res[$o][f] = $row[$o];
    }
    json_encode($res);
?>
```

This is getData.js file. The file file receive res and will be passed to 'mp'.

```
<script>
    function aha() {
    $.ajax({
        url:'arrivalPlay.php',
        data:{id:3},
        dataType:'json',
        type:'GET',
        success:function(data){
            document.write(data[1].f);
            document.write(data[2].f);
            document.write(data[3].f);
            document.write(data[4].f);
        }
    });
    }
</script>
```

Page arrivalPlay.php only has data if the url become arrivalPlay.php?id=X. Is there any way to retrieve data from the 'dynamic' php to the javascript page? Feel free to change my approach if you think it is odd. Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

First in your server page apply `echo` before `json_encode($res);`

It should be `echo json_encode($res);`

And then if it not works then try this code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','#a',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url:'arrivalPlay.php',
            data:{id:1},
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(data){
                $('#res').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

If you want `json` from server then only `json data` should be passed from `server`

like in your code

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","admin","admin","flight_status");
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $getrow = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM arrival WHERE id='$id'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($getrow);
    mysqli_close($con); 
    $res=array();
    $order = array('airline','flight','origin','status');
    foreach ($order as $o) {
        $res[$o] = $row[$o];
    }
    echo json_encode($res);// echo the json string
    // remember that no other output should be generated other than this json
    return; //so you can use this line
?>
```

is enough

**but** you don't want `json` then you use this code

`echo implode(',',$res);` **instead of** `echo json_encode($res);`

also in `javascript` remove this option `dataType:'json',` in this case.

Read [jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax)

Comment: Sorry for late answer. The echo did print content of '$res'. The code above is not working, my javascript doesn't load a thing. I wonder why.

Comment: @epndkempot Try the above and also `check` that you have `added` any `version` of `jquery`, before using it.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I use json and remove unnecessary element. In receiver side now can print "null -- 1 null -- 2 null -- 3 null -- 4". If I change to '$.getJSON('arrivalPlay.php?id=1', it retrieve the data.

Comment: @epndkempot Did you add `dataType:'json'` in `ajax function`. Also add `type:'GET'` in that function

Comment: not yet----yes, I use both of them. Thanks! It can retrieve the data from {id:1}. Now, is there anyway to retrieve data without put data:{id:1}?

Comment: Then tell me how you can get result from `database` without `$id`?

Comment: It needs the $id. I mean how could I pass the $id to the ajax script?

Comment: So you can pass id to function `aha()` like `aha(id)` and use in `ajax function` like `data:{id:id}`

Comment: I mean from the php, but I'll sort this later. Anyway, thank you for your help rohan :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are receiving JSON data, I doubt that you would like to place them into an HTML element. I would either change my PHP file to produce HTML elements, or implement som javascript logic to create elements based on the JSON data the server provides.

Comment: Thank you... I store the $res data to an array. Now I'm dealing to recieve it in js